# Assign closest data point information from one DataFrame to each point in another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have a couple of DataFrames that contain different information.

One DataFrame, named `atm_data`, contains several data points and associated columns with values at a spatial resolution of over 1km. The other DataFrame, named `gridded_data`, contains thousands of rows containing longitude and latitude values at a much higher spatial resolution (30 meters). What I want to do is take the data in the `gridded_data` DataFrame and assign the nearest associated data from the data points in the `atm_data` DataFrame.

Here's the code I'm trying to use, but I keep getting the error: '''ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels.

```
lat_lon_points = atm_data[['lat','lon']].values
lat_lon_gridded = gridded_data[['lat','lon']].values

distances = cdist(lat_lon_gridded, lat_lon_points, metric='euclidean')

nearest_indices = np.argmin(distances, axis=1)

gridded_data = gridded_data.reset_index(drop=True)

gridded_data[['var1','var2','var3','var4','var5']] = atm_data[['var1','var2','var3','var4','var5']].iloc[nearest_indices]
```

I had to reset the index of the `gridded_data` because it was selected from a previous DataFrame.

Any suggestions/advice/help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit**: I see that the TypeError is occurring because the variable being called is not a DataFrame. I removed that error. However, I am still receiving the error I noted above.

Comment: How large are these data frames? Also, if you fixed the original error then please update the code accordingly.

Comment: Apologies, just did that. The above code is what I am currently working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the GeoPandas package for this.

As long as your two spatial dataframes are in the same coordinate system, you can use this to join the nearest data points together:

```
geopandas.sjoin_nearest()
```

This will create a many-to-one relationship where multiple `atm_data` points may have the attributes of the same `gridded_data`.

You can read about the function here: https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin_nearest.html

Comment: That seemed to do the trick, thank you!